# One Signal App Push Notification kill server

Tags: onesignal

After sending One Signal App push notification from our backend(manual) code,the server down(kill) but restarted after 5 minutes automactically.These problem occured large users(My side more than 150000)How to fix these issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to `OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js.php` and `OneSignalSDKWorker.js.php` being fetched by browsers when a notification is received. This can be taxing if you have a large number of subscribers since these files will be fetched when receiving a notification if the browser hasn't in the past 24 hours.

### Solutions

#### Solution 1 - Setup a CDN

You can setup a free [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) account which can cache these files as well as other pages on your site to greatly lower the load on your server.

#### Solution 2 - Per-User Optimization

Notifications can be sent over a 24 hour period based on the last time they visited your site or based on a specific time in their timezone. This will help spread when your site will be loaded over time.
***This does not apply to notifications sent through the default send on post option. Only to notifications sent through OneSignal's dashboard, REST API, or if [custom PHP is added with a filter hook](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-wordpress-faq#section-wordpress-users-only) to add this delay option.***
[image]

#### Solution 3 - os.tc Subdomain For New Sites

**(Not Recommended)**
If your setting up a new site you can our HTTP option instead of HTTPS as these service worker files will be hosted by os.tc for you. However, note that the HTTP has limitations on prompting options and shows a pop-up window to subscribe. Also, all notifications and the notification permission will show `yoursite.os.tc` instead of just `yoursite`.

### Other Possible Issue

Also, make sure your notification icon is not hosted on your domain as this will be an extra request to your server when you send a notification.

Comment: I need a solution for Android platform app push notification but push notification send from php code